# Convert Ordereddict into dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to convert ordereddict into dataframe. Please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
d = OrderedDict([('status', 1), ('previous_count', 0), ('current_count', 0), ('error_msg', ''), ('error_func', ''), ('query', '')])
```

I am doing below code-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d.items())
```

it's printing--->>

```
                0  1
0          status  1
1  previous_count  0
2   current_count  0
3       error_msg
4      error_func
5           query
```

But I want result in below format-

```
     status     previous_count   current_count    error_msg   error_func    query
0     1             0                 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `columns` as the dictionary keys (`d` or `d.keys()`) and the row as a list of the items:

```
pd.DataFrame([d.values()], columns=d)
```

Or pass an index (here `[0]`):

```
pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
```

output:

```
   status  previous_count  current_count error_msg error_func query
0       1               0              0
```